# How to write this ifelse statement in R correctly

Tags: r, if-statement

I  want to return a value in a column, or NA, contingent on values in other columns.

I basically want to see if the value in the column meets the first test criteria:

```
df$v2.1 >= df$varx & df$v3.1 <6
```

if not does it meet the second:

```
 df$v4.1 >= df$vary & df$v5.1 >5
```

and then if neither return `NA`

The code I have tried is below.

```
df$v1.1 = ifelse(df$v2.1 >= df$varx & df$v3.1 <6 || df$v4.1 >= df$vary & df$v5.1 >5 ,df$v1.1, NA)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell df$v1.1 is already defined, so you only need to modify those rows that fail the test in your ifelse. The following might be easier:

```
 df$v1.1[
   which(
     !(df$v2.1 >= df$varx & df$v3.1 <6) & !(df$v4.1 >= df$vary & df$v5.1 >5))
   ] <- NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Your only mistake is using `||` rather than `|`. `||` is not vectorised, and only considers the first element. All your other operators (and `ifelse()`) are vectorised, so the following should work as expected:

```
df$v1.1 = ifelse(df$v2.1 >= df$varx & df$v3.1 <6 | df$v4.1 >= df$vary & df$v5.1 > 5, df$v1.1, NA)
```

A good way to check when you're doing reasonably complex or multiple logical operations is to run each one of them and see if you're getting the expected output. If you run:

```
df$v2.1 >= df$varx & df$v3.1 <6
```

or

```
df$v4.1 >= df$vary & df$v5.1 > 5
```

you should get a vector of logical values. If you run:

```
df$v2.1 >= df$varx & df$v3.1 <6 || df$v4.1 >= df$vary & df$v5.1 > 5
```

you should get a single logical value. In your case, that will give a single result from the `ifelse()`, which then gets recycled to fill `df$v1.1`.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this worked for me as well as the answer below. The explanation was much appreciated.